# Can I have notepad not encode my files?

Tags: java, encoding, windows-xp, notepad, mac-roman

I have a notepad file. Well, its more of a .java file. The text is in Western MAC OS Roman (MacRoman) But when I save it, it gives me choices of how to encode it. Except, if I encode it, Java can't understand it! How can I have notepad **NOT** encode my files?

Comment: You mean encode I suppose. Why do you use notepad at all?

Comment: Go grab a copy of [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) and call it good..

Comment: @assylias Encode yes, and unfortunately Notepad is all I have right now, I am looking into alternative software. Like Mike Christensen recommended Notepad2. I haven't forgot you.

Comment: @Flarp If you can use alternatives, why not install a proper IDE like eclipse, netbeans or intellij?

Comment: @assylias i haven't seen them before. Again, I am a serious noob, so I  am trying to learn. But thanks for bringing those upon me. I think NetBeans look cool.

Comment: @Flarp Netbeans is probably easier if you have never used an IDE before. It sort of works out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save your file without any encoding at all.
Whatever you do, it is still encoded in some way.
I suggest you encode it in UTF-8, then every decent
editor (including Java IDEs) will understand it.

Comment: So if notepad isn't good... what should I use? And off-topic, did my profile picture change?

Comment: Notepad supports UTF-8. It is not an advanced editor but it works for me in some occasions :) Yes, your picture is changed now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an encoding prompt, it is because there are non-ASCII characters in the text. Therefore, you must choose an encoding of some kind for those non-ASCII characters. You need to select an encoding which is understood by your IDE or whatever environment is loading the text. Normally, UTF-8 is understood by pretty much everything these days.

Comment: Even if the text is in MacRoman? That means it would be double encoding, just saying.

Comment: @Flarp There can only be one encoding - it can't be MacRoman and UTF-8 at the same time.